# How to return all values in a table when no parameter info is selected by user

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, reporting-services

I would like to create parameters in SSRS that return all values in the table if no specific values are selected by the user. I'll make the prompt say something like: "*Leave blank to view all info*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could explicitly check for a `null` there. E.g., assuming the column is `value` and the input variable is `:input`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  :input IS NULL OR :input = value
```